# How to use aggregate function to filter a dataset in ssrs 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a matrix in ssrs2008 like below:

```
GroupName   Zone    CompletedVolume 
Cancer      1       7
Tunnel      1       10
Surgery     1       64
```

ComplatedVolume value is coming by a specific expression `<<expr>>`, which is equal to: `[Max(CVolume)]`

This matrix is filled by a stored procedure that I am not supposed to change if possible. What I need to do is that not to show the data whose CompletedVolume is <= 50. I tried to go to tablix properties and add a filter like `[Max(Q9Volume)] >= 50`, but when I try to run the report it says that `aggregate functions cannot be used in dataset filters or data region filters.` How can I fix this as easy as possible?

Note that adding a where clause in sql query would not solve this issue since there are many other tables use the same SP and they need the data where CompletedVolume <= 50. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am trying to have the max(Q9Volume) value on SP, but something happening I have never seen before. The query is like:

```
Select r.* from (select * from results1 union select * from results2) r 
left outer join procedures p on r.pid = p.id
```

The interesting this is there are some columns I see that does not included by neither results1/results2 nor procedures tables when I run the query. For example, there is no column like Q9Volume in the tables (result1, result2 and procedures), however when I run the query I see the columns on the output! How is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried:  `where CompletedValume >= 50`?  I don't see why an aggregate would be necessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, OP is calculating CompletedVolume by using an aggregation expression on SSRS. What you proposed could work using `HAVING` clause in the SP query.

Comment: Use `Q9Volume >= 50`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the Row hidden property to True when `[Max(CVolume)]` is less or equal than 50.

Select the row and go to Row Visibility

[image]

Select *Show or Hide based on an expression* option and use this expression:

```
=IIF(
Max(Fields!Q9Volume.Value)<=50,
True,False
)
```

It will show something like this:

[image]

> Note maximum value for Cancer and Tunnel are 7 and 10 respectively, so
>   they will be hidden if you apply the above expression.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! You are my hero for ssrs2008